VS2022 - Disable StyleCop for specific configuration
I'm using StyleCop on my project via the nuget package.
I'd like to only have it active when using a specific configuration profile so I can easily toggle it on and off, So I've created a new configuration profile named 'Debug_StyleCop' and created this conditional property on my .csproj:
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)' != 'Debug_StyleCop'">
    <!-- Suppress all StyleCop warnings -->
    <NoWarn>
      SA0001,SA0002,SA1000,SA1001,SA1002,SA1003,SA1004,SA1005,SA1006,SA1007,SA1008,SA1009,SA1010,SA1011,SA1012,SA1013,SA1014,SA1015,SA1016,SA1017,SA1018,SA1019,SA1020,SA1021,SA1022,SA1023,SA1024,SA1025,SA1026,SA1027,SA1028,SA1100,SA1101,SA1102,SA1103,SA1104,SA1105,SA1106,SA1107,SA1108,SA1109,SA1110,SA1111,SA1112,SA1113,SA1114,SA1115,SA1116,SA1117,SA1118,SA1119,SA1120,SA1121,SA1122,SA1123,SA1124,SA1125,SA1126,SA1127,SA1128,SA1129,SA1130,SA1131,SA1132,SA1133,SA1134,SA1135,SA1136,SA1137,SA1139,SA1141,SA1142,SA1200,SA1201,SA1202,SA1203,SA1204,SA1205,SA1206,SA1207,SA1208,SA1209,SA1210,SA1211,SA1212,SA1213,SA1214,SA1215,SA1216,SA1217,SA1300,SA1301,SA1302,SA1303,SA1304,SA1305,SA1306,SA1307,SA1308,SA1309,SA1310,SA1311,SA1312,SA1313,SA1314,SA1316,SA1400,SA1401,SA1402,SA1403,SA1404,SA1405,SA1406,SA1407,SA1408,SA1409,SA1410,SA1411,SA1412,SA1413,SA1414,SA1500,SA1501,SA1502,SA1503,SA1504,SA1505,SA1506,SA1507,SA1508,SA1509,SA1510,SA1511,SA1512,SA1513,SA1514,SA1515,SA1516,SA1517,SA1518,SA1519,SA1520,SA1600,SA1601,SA1602,SA1603,SA1604,SA1605,SA1606,SA1607,SA1608,SA1609,SA1610,SA1611,SA1612,SA1613,SA1614,SA1615,SA1616,SA1617,SA1618,SA1619,SA1620,SA1621,SA1622,SA1623,SA1624,SA1625,SA1626,SA1627,SA1628,SA1629,SA1630,SA1631,SA1632,SA1633,SA1634,SA1635,SA1636,SA1637,SA1638,SA1639,SA1640,SA1641,SA1642,SA1643,SA1644,SA1645,SA1646,SA1647,SA1648,SA1649,SA1650,SA1651,SA1652,SX1101,SX1309,SX1309S
    </NoWarn>
  </PropertyGroup>

This looks pretty stupid, and it probably is, but I haven't found any other way to supress all stylecop warnings with a condition like that, is there a better way to do this?

As this is a third party package the support could be limited.If your project can be compiled with msbuild,try add error/warning message in
Project Settings > Build > Suppress warnings .

You are asking for an easy way to toggle this configuration on and off.
You can always comment out out the content of the NoWarn tags in the csproj file. Open the file, click on the line and use your preferred keyboard shortcut to comment / uncomment the current line.
That's as quick, if not quicker than going into project settings, or tools / options or some other config file, no?
